# React/Javascript: Map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql-js, map-function

I have tried everything I know about map functions and the syntax but I keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined`.  I think the source of the problem is this line: `constructor(data=[])`. Firstly, I have never seen into inside the brackets of constructor other than props `constructor(props)`. So, not sure what is going on there.

I am reading a book on React/D3 and the author renders a timeline of dots from a static array of key/value pairs. I am trying render the same graph but my data is coming from a DB. Can someone help me refactor my code below to account for a DB request to grab 'data' before rendering?

Book COde:

```
constructor({data=[]}) {
        const times = d3.extent(data.map(d => d.year))
        const range = [50, 450]
        super({data})
        this.state = {data, times, range}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let group
        const { data, times, range } = this.state
        const { target } = this.refs
        const scale = d3.time.scale().domain(times).range(range)
```

My code:

```
    constructor(data=[]) {

        const times = d3.extent(data.action.action.map(action => action.timestamp))
        const range = [50, 450]
        super({data})
        this.scale = d3.scaleTime().domain(times).range(range)
        this.state = {times, range}
        console.log('state' ,this.data);
    }

render() {
    const { data } = this.state
    const { scale } = this
    return (
        <div className="timeline">
            <h1>{this.props.name} Timeline</h1>
            <Canvas>
                {data.map((d, i) => 
                    <TimelineDot position={scale(d.year)} 
                                 txt={`${d.year} - ${d.event}`}
                    />
                )}
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    )
    }
}
```

My data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be **data.action.map** instead of **data.action.action.map**

Comment: Now I am getting this: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Comment: I think the reason for the map being undefined is the DB request for data is sent manual when a submit button is pressed not upon rendering of the program or from a static dataset like in the book.

Answer (score 1):

You removed initial empty `data` property definition in constructor

```
this.state = {data, times, range} // book
this.state = {times, range}       // your code
```

Empty `data` can be mapped w/o error. By removing it's undefined - how it could work?

`constructor({data=[]})` is just default props initialized with empty data array passed later to base class (by super({data}) where is probably set in state? W/o that `const { data } = this.state` should be undefined, unable to be used in map. In book code `data` is directly defined in state - is your code up to date?